# Why remix stuck on pending status when sending transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ethereumjs

I created a helloworld contract in Remix and I am able to deploy it to a testing network. But when I click the method `sendMessage`, I can see there is a log in the bottom panel but it is on pending. It stuck there for hours. Is there anything I missed?

[image]

Comment: Did you try ctrl-R / hard refresh ? iirc, Remix pushed a new version yesterday, don't know if it's related (deploying/sending transactions on javaVM should be instant)

Comment: yes refresh seems working thanks